# Is there a way to get top-most View of all visible things on android?

Tags: android

Is there any way to find the top-most `View` object that includes every layout including status bar, home drawer and everything currently exists in android screen?

Comment: The topmost view of everything that exists on the screen would be 0, wouldn't it?

Comment: you can try getWindow().getDecorView() but of course it doesn't include the status bar which belongs to the OS

Answer (score 0):

No, mostly because that stuff is not in your process.